# How can I let my if statement wait for get request to complete ( GUARD ) using angular

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

I want to create admin routes for my angular app. I've created a role guard in angular. See my code below.

Now I want my get request to complete before my if statement starts checking if the user is an admin. Is there a way to do this?

```
export class RoleGuardGuard implements CanActivate {

  public user;

  constructor( private apiService: ApiService ) {}

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {

      this.apiService.getUserAdminData().subscribe((data)=>{
        this.user = data;
      });

      if (this.user.user_role === 'admin') {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't subscribe, return an observable. Something like

```
return this.apiService.getUserAdminData().pipe(
    tap(user => this.user = user),
    map(user => user.user_role === 'admin')
);
```